# ¿Un Rollback en una transaccion, revierte los cambios de procedures que se ejecutan dentro de la transacción?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo tres Stored procedures: sp1, sp2 y sp3.

El sp1 inicia una transacción y dentro de esta transacción se ejecuta el sp2, el cual a su vez ejecuta el sp3 (es decir, sp3 está contenido en sp2). sp2 y sp3 NO inician transacción, la única transacción existente es la de sp1.

Si existe un rollback en sp1, la preguntas es:

**¿Rrevierte los cambios realizados en sp2 y sp3?**

A continuación agrego codigo para que sea mas fácil de visualizar la situación:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP1
AS
BEGIN
BEGIN TRAN

--Algo de codigo

EXEC SP2

--Aquí ocurre un ROLLBACK
ROLLBACK TRAN
END
```

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP2
AS 
BEGIN

--Se ejecuta sp3
EXEC SP3
END
```

Una vez más recalco, solo SP1 inicia transacción

Comment: Depende de lo que hagan Sp2 y Sp2,  pero de forma general, si se trata de sentencias SQL, efectivamente se revierten los cambios de Sp1 y Sp2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depende lo lo que haga el sp2, pero si sp1 falla  sp1 seria porque algo falla en sp2 o sp2, de la forma q lo haz planteado. Pero básicamente cualquera que falle te disparara el rollback y no se guardaran los cambios de ninguno.